# SELECT columns EXCEPT values that are loaded from file

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

Let's say i have table `Table1`:

```
|Column1|Column2|Column3|
|1      |25     |a      |
|2      |48     |a      |
|3      |25     |b      |
|4      |25     |d      |
|5      |16     |e      |
```

And i have command:

`"SELECT Column1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE Column2 = 25)";`

So now output is:

```
1
3
4
```

Now i want to do the same but if column3 = a, then do not select that row, so output is now:

```
3
4
```

And now i want A to be loaded from txt file, but in that file would be more values (a, b, d, g, u...)

So basicly i want to

`SELECT [columns] FROM [table] WHERE [column1] = 1 EXCEPT [column2] = [values from txt]`

I just need logic for command, i know everything other.

Comment: You meant `[column3] = [values from txt]` no? column2 is integers but 3 is your letters/values

Comment: @FirstStep From .txt files, it will be int

Comment: Why have you tagged _mysql_ **and** _firebird_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add AND [column2] NOT IN [values from txt]:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table]
WHERE [column1] = 1 AND [column2] NOT IN  (a, b, d, g, u...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with `UNION` then know that `EXCEPT` works in a very similar way e.g. the two table expressions must have the same number of columns with the same data types, in left-to-right order, etc.

```
SELECT [columns]
  FROM [table]
 WHERE [column1] = 1 
EXCEPT
SELECT [columns]
  FROM [table]
 WHERE [column2] = [values from txt]
```

The way you are using `EXCEPT` is more like SQL's `WHERE..ALL` syntax e.g. something like:

```
SELECT [columns]
  FROM [table]
 WHERE [column1] = 1 
       AND [column2] <> ALL ( SELECT [values from txt] FROM ?somewhere? );
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: @abarisone: any better?